# persistent access denied message when debugging project using IIS Express and Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, iis-express

I'm debugging my NetCore 3.1 project in Visual Studio 2019.  I am doing this locally using the built-in IIS Express on Windows 10.

I am trying to save files to my D: drive.

I'm getting the error below when I try to copy a file to the local file system when running my Visual Studio project in debug mode using IIS Express:

```
{"Access to the path 'D:\\biologyMedia\\eb4cf4c2-6434-4cfe-9fa8-0033bc9b1a08' is denied."}
```

The error happens in the method below in the try block:

```
public async Task<bool> CopyFile(IFormFile examFile, Guid diseaseId)
{
    string path = @"D:\biologyMedia\" + diseaseId + @"\";

    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }

    try
    {
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await examFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        var error = e.InnerException;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Based on previous answers, I've tried the following:

- Set Windows Authentication to enabled in the project properties
- Started Visual Studio as Administrator
- Given complete control of the
  D: drive to LOCAL SERVICE, NETWORK SERVICE, IUSR, IIS_USERS, and
  NETWORK, and my own Windows account(which is a member of
  Administrator).

I'm not sure what else I can try.

Anyone ever fix this before?

Thanks!

Comment: Try deleting the folder `biologyMedia`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skye, sorry, but could it be that your path in

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await examFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }
```

is actually the folder **@"D:\biologyMedia\" + diseaseId + @"\";** and therefore not a filename?

So you are trying to copy a file ONTO a folder not INTO it?

Comment: Hi well I first create the path, which would look like : "D:\biologyMedia\394837\" Then I use that path when I copy the file

Comment: yes but I think you need to do something like ```new FileStream(path+"filename", FileMode.Create)``` so the filestream 'points' to a file for the copy operation

Answer (score 2):

I have had similar adventures in the past, with IIS, but I have never worked with IIS Express. In my case I had to grant the application pool user access to the folder.

See :  https://support.pkware.com/home/smar/latest/sem-knowledge-base/kb-granting-folder-permissions-to-iis-application-pools

I suggest you check your applicationhost.config to examine your application pools in IIS Express.  And ensure that the application pool of IIS Express has complete control of the folder `D:\biologyMedia`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks but unfortunately that doesn't work for IIS Express

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you save the files to a folder under the root of your application. While I can't explain the problem you are having, you will be much better off writing your code in such a way that it doesn't access folders outside your app root.